# Consecutive destructure statement issue

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to remove the user_id field from 2 different objects but get a compile error. what is the correct way ?

```
const  { user_id, ...userLessId } = user


const { user_id, ...zombieLessId } = existingZombieUser
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign these variables to different names, otherwise your `user_id` will be defined twice, which cause an SyntaxError.

```js
const  { user_id: user_id1, ...userLessId } = user

const { user_id: user_id2, ...zombieLessId } = existingZombieUser
```

You have to avoid the SyntaxError, so you can also reassign just one variable:

```js
const { user_id, ...userLessId } = user;
const { user_id: zombieUserId, ...zombieLessId } = existingZombieUser;
```

Comment: You can also use arrow functions to create a one-liner: `const userWithoutId = (({ user_id, ...x }) => x)(user);` Of course one may extract the function into a named helper function to reuse it in the second case without having to redefine it.